# Script to check whether all mails replied in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

We use Lotusnotes 6.5 as email client. We wil have around 1600+ mails for 9 hrs. If a mail not checked , we have face serious issues with our client. Can any script can be written to check whether all mails are checked and replied?

#### Update:

We have already tried moving the mails to another folder.But has this mailbox handled by team of persons, we noticed lot of human error happening like moving a unread mail, sometimes they would have read mail but forget to reply it etc.etc.

So I was looking out for a script solution, will your other options. Also one more thing we do is we cc our mailbox mail id for all outgoing emails to have a track of all replied mails, will this could help in any way to find out which mails was missed?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to track unread marks, I second the aforementioned nsftools solution, which works in Domino 7.x too. However, this is very much Notes ID-dependent. A folder would be better.

Note that 6.5x is *well* out of support, and that Domino 7.x officially died this week: use something at least *vaguely* modern!

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier non-programmatic way.  Just move the email from the inbox into another folder once the email has been responded to.  That is more reliable than any programmatic solution, and keeps your inbox tidy (which will certainly be necessary if you get nearly 200 emails per hour!)

That said, here are some other ideas.

**Determining if the document was read**

Unread marks are not your friend here, unless you'll be accessing the mail file from the same client.  Also they tend to get out of sync and would likely prove unreliable at some point, especially given the number of incoming emails.  Instead you'll need to have some information that is saved within the individual mail document, such as the last accessed property or a custom item you manage via scripts/formulas.

You can see if an email has been read by checking the Last Accessed property of the mail document.  According to IBM's technote (https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21086670), the property will be updated when the document is read.

You could write a script in the QueryOpen event that stamps a value on the document and saves it.

**Determining if the email was responded to**

First off, I'd suggest you save all sent emails in case you need a record of what was sent to the client. That won't give you a way to see which emails have not been responded to, however.

Instead you could add script to the reply action within the memo form.  When someone click's reply it could update the current memo, stamping an item on it to say who replied and at what time, for instance.  Then you can create a view to show any emails that don't have that item, and another view to show emails that do grouped by who responded.  The second view could even show how many emails each person responded to, something that might be used as a measurement of performance perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

"Unread mark" checking is not exposed in the API.

I did find 2 links, [this](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Show-unread-marked-Lotus-Notes-email-messages-using-LotusScript) one is a basic implementation, where as this [link](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/UnreadDocListClass.lss.htm) does have more robust code and is implemented as an object in LotusScript. It should be compatible with Notes 6.5+.

I found the second link through [nsftools](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/NotesTips.htm#unreaddocs) website which has lots of great snippets that solve various problems. You should at least be able to detect if a mail has been read or not. Note that it requires making API level calls. You should be able to create a new script library and copy/paste the code into it.